# Trouble changing icons on ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu, android-support-library

My application calls a web service on startup to see if the user is logged in. If they are logged in it needs to show a logout icon. If they aren't logged in, it needs to show a login icon. If their version of the application doesn't support logging in, it need to continue showing no icon.

How do I get the icon to show when the web service returns?  I can't call invalidateOptionsMenu() because I'm using 2.3. Also, if I try to add it in onPrepareOptionsMenu() it shows up on the menu when you press the menu button instead of on the ActionBar.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar this way:

In your action bar menu, have both the log in and log out items already there (I would advise putting them in an xml instead of creating it in the code so you can easily assign the items an id).  Then just hold a reference to your menu when you create it so you can modify it later.

```
Menu myActionBarMenu;

/**
 * Creates action bar items.
 */
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menuNameHere, menu);
    myActionBarMenu = menu;
}
```

Then, when you find out the user is logged in, set the visibility of the log in item to false like this:

```
myActionBarMenu.findItem(R.id.logInAction).setVisible(false);
myActionBarMenu.findItem(R.id.logOutAction).setVisible(true);
```

reverse the visibility in the case the user is logged out.

This would be what your xml menu would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/logInAction"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Log In"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/logOutAction"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Log Out"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: I get an error when using myActionBarMenu.findItem(R.id.logInAction).setVisible(false);
-> since findItem return MenuItem and that does not have setVisible method!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  See the documentation for  android.view.MenuItem (developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setVisible(boolean)).  setVisible is a method on android.view.MenuItem.  I'm using ActionBarSherlock in my project, and it's a method in the corresponding MenuItem as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to add menu items to the ActionBar:

```
/*************************************/
/* Create the actionbar options menu */
/*************************************/
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    menu.add("Settings")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    return true;
}
```

You should be able to add an if statement in there and change the icon accordingley

Comment: The form displays while the web service is being called so onCreateOptionsMenu() has already been called.  I need to be able to change the icon at any point during the lifecycle of the application

Comment: Ah ok. I misunderstood. Are you using the compatibility library for the ActionBar? If so I think  invalidateOptionsMenu() is available if you extend FragmentActivity

Comment: I am extending FragmentActivity.  When I call invalidateOptionsMenu() I get a NoSuchMethodError

Comment: supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() ... should be available

Comment: Eclipse says supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() is not visible.

Comment: I am currently using ActionBarSherlock for backwards compatability, supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); works in there. Have you considered using this library?